# jQuery - issue with global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem maybe an inexperience of using global variable which causes some problem.

Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZgXKx/ When you click the **click me!** I am dynamically  setting up the id for some elements using the global variable.

I'm having problem with this code:

```
$("#service-sets").on('click', "#facebook-del-"+a, function() {           
    var aa = $("#facebook-del-"+a).parent().parent().parent().attr("id");
    $('#'+aa).remove();
```

where it is not entering into the click event because `"#facebook-del-"+a` in `.on('click')` is not working, whereas the one inside the click event is working(showing the value `"#facebook-del-1"`).

When I changed the code like this, It has no problem

```
$("#service-sets").on('click', "#facebook-del-1", function() {           
    var aa = $("#facebook-del-"+a).parent().parent().parent().attr("id");
    $('#'+aa).remove();
```

You can check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/ZgXKx/1/

So what is the mistake I've done?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the variable 'a' in `"#facebook-del-"+a`?

Comment: It is a global variable 'a'. Please check the jsfiddle I've given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#service-sets").on('click', "[id^=facebook-del]", function() {          
    $(this).closest('div.tag').remove();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/qxKHg/)**

Here,

`[id^=facebook-del]` is those element (cross), who's `id` start with `facebook-el`. So set delegate event like this will not need any indexing with global variable `a`.

`$(this).closest('div.tag')` target to `div.tag`, which is container of clicked cross.

Comment: Yes, this is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the fact that, contrary to what it looks like, that "a" variable is **not** global. It's inside a function created for you by jsfiddle itself.

Set the control on the left to have your code placed in the `<head>` instead of in an "onload" handler, and it'll work.

Also, there's no reason to do what you're doing with that code to remove the added markup. That is, the process of finding an element, getting its "id" value, and then re-finding it via the "id" is pointless.  Once you've found the element with those ".parent()" calls (which itself is a pretty fragile way of doing things; it'd be much better to give the outer wrapper a class and then use `.closest(".whatever")`), you've got it, and there's no reason to find it again.

*edit* — now that I think of it, though what I said about "a" is true — that it's not really global — it shouldn't matter in this case.  It is however a frequent cause of irritation with jsfiddle (bless their hearts nevertheless, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You don't increment `a` until inside the callback for clicking on `#facebook-button`. When this runs:

```
$("#service-sets").on('click', "#facebook-del-"+a, function() {           
    ..
});
```

`a` is still 0, and you only every handle click events for `#facebook-del-0` which never will exist.

You can use a class for deleting instead. Give your close button the class "facebook-del" and then use this to close it:

```
$("#service-sets").on('click', '.facebook-del', function() {           
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/ZgXKx/3/)